# Why can't I suppress Android lint via comment

Tags: android, android-lint

For some lint checks I can suppress them with a comment or a method annotation. `ConstantConditions` is a good example:

[image: Android Studio screenshot showing multiple suppress options]

However for other checks I can only suppress via a method annotation. `CheckResult` is an example.

[image: Android Studio screenshot showing only one option]

Is there any reason for this difference? Is it just that Android tools team hasn't added a comment-based suppression check?

Comment: Just making sure you are aware of this page: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint

Comment: @MorrisonChang yep. I'm familiar with the lint docs. What specifically on that page do you think answers my question?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, Android Studio comes with a two sets of inspections:

1. inspections from Intellij IDEA
2. inspections from Android Lint

So, `ConstantConditions` is an Intellij IDEA inspection, and `CheckResult` is coming from Android Lint.

I think the reason that Android Lint checks usually disabled with `@SuppressLint` annotation is just that it's technically easier to understand that check is suppressed or not for a particular source code element.

Actually, you can suppress a check will comment like this:

```
//noinspection CheckResult
```

But it only works when running lint from the command line, but not in Android Studio.